# Python- cannot get a list of values in for loop when there are numbers in json structures

Tags: python, json

I was trying to to get all the types inside a colours->numbers but it doesn't work because the colours e.g. green,blue inside an integer so i could not go through a loop to get them.

Here is the code that I was trying to do:

```
x=0
for colour in colours['rootdata']: 
    
    print(colour[x][type])
    x+1
```

but is shows 'string indices must be integers'

I'm able to get a single value with for loop like this :(but this not what i want)

```
colour_red = JsonResult['rootdata']['colours']['0']['type']
print (colour_red )
```

This is the simple json sample that I'm using

```
{
    "rootdata": {


        "colours": {
            "0": {
                "type": "red"

            },
            "1": {
                "type": "green"

            },
            "2": {
                "type": "blue"

            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you iterate through a dict with "for" you only get the keys. "colours['rootdata']" isn't the dict you want to iterate through as it only has one key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```py
my_dict = {"rootdata": 
    {
        "colours": {"0": {"type": "red"}, "1": {"type": "green"}, "2": {"type": "blue"}}
    }
}
types = []
types_dict = {}

for k, v in my_dict["rootdata"]["colours"].items():
    types.append(v["type"])
    types_dict[k] = v["type"]
    
print(types)
#   R e s u l t :    ['red', 'green', 'blue']

print(types_dict)
#   R e s u l t :   {'0': 'red', '1': 'green', '2': 'blue'}
```

Regards...

Comment: Why `items` if you only use `v`?

Comment: Just in case that there is a need to create a dictionary (instead of list) with those keys. It is unclear what type should be the result.

Comment: Now it is edited with dictionary...

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use a counter. You can obtain the colours by using the following code:

```
for colour in colours['rootdata']['colours'].values(): 
  print(colour['type'])
```

This code is works even if the numbers are not in sequential order in the json, and the order of the output does not really matter.